# in react useEffect hook not triggering with updated data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of people and im trying to display a title according to the selected person the user clicked.
Im using a useState to set the selected person but because the useState is async im using useEffect to set the title when the selectedPerson is updated, but the when the useEffect is triggered im getting the previous selected person and not the new one

I tried the following:

```
const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState({});
const [summaryTitle, setSummaryTitle] = useState("");

const onSelectPerson = (person) => {
  setSelectedPerson(person)
}
```

because this is async I added the useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSummaryTitle(selectedPerson.firstName + " " + selectedPerson.lastName)
}, [selectedPerson]);
```

The problem is, when selectedPerson is updated and the useEffect is triggered the value of the selectedPerson is the previous selection the user clicked.

for example:

if the user clicked on Bill the value of the selectedPerson in the useEffect is empty object.
then the user clicked on James the value of the selectedPerson in the useEffect is Bill and so on

did anyone came across anything like this? can anyone help?

Comment: Looks right to me. How are you calling `onSelectPerson`?

Comment: I am calling onSelectPerson like so: onClick={() => onSelectPerson(person)}

Comment: Need the code of the component with the issue, I feel like you are not passing the person properly as an argument!

Comment: OHHHHHH  I can`t believe I missed it, you are right, some very inner component send the previous person. Thank you!